# What's the packer/encrypter used with this file

Tags: disassembly, unpacking, packers

I used PEiD & Stud_PE to get the packer/encrypter signature but unfortunately they didn't detect it.

[image]

could someone help with this issue?

**EDIT:**
As @beatcracker said in comments, using ExeinfoPe says:
[image]

Comment: Looks like the section names are randomly generated. Try to feed this file to  [Exeinfo PE](http://www.exeinfo.xn.pl).

Comment: Unwrapper for GOTD installers: [UnWrapper GOTD V2 Saves the Latest Giveawayoftheday Setup Files](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/unwrapper-gotd-saves-newer-giveawayoftheday-setup-installer-file/)

Comment: @beatcracker: it's not a Giveawayoftheday Setup File as the unpacker said, thank you for your help, my question is: is there a native exe unpacker for Themida ?

Comment: Themida is very hard to unpack (even the new driverless versions), there is a ton of protections options that can be enabled (see [manual](http://www.oreans.com/ThemidaHelp.pdf)), so I doubt that there is a generic unpacker in the wild. Try this tutotial: [How Unpack Themida 2.x.x](http://forum.xentax.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=12953)

Comment: @beatcracker: it worked like a charm, you have to change your comment into a valid answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I used PEiD & Stud_PE to get the packer/encrypter signature but
> unfortunately they didn't detect it.

[Exeinfo PE](http://www.exeinfo.xn.pl) has more recent signatures (beware of gifs, though).

> **EDIT:** As @beatcracker said in comments, using ExeinfoPe says:
>
> *Detected Themida v2.x Inside, Themida Code on Section*.
>
> Is there a native exe unpacker for Themida ?

Themida is very hard to unpack (even the new driverless versions), there is a ton of protections options that can be enabled (see [manual](http://www.oreans.com/ThemidaHelp.pdf)), so I doubt that there is a generic unpacker in the wild.

Try this tutotial: [How Unpack Themida 2.x.x](http://forum.xentax.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=12953). It uses OllyDbg script which hides most of the complexity required to unpack\fix Themida.

#### References:

- [Original link to sript's author post on Tuts4You (requires registration to view)](https://forum.tuts4you.com/topic/34085-themida-winlicense-ultra-unpacker-14/)
- Files from the post above (includes video converted to `exe`, I've not checked it so be careful): [Themida - Winlicense Ultra Unpacker 1.4 - Tutorial.rar](https://www.sendspace.com/file/9pu8z8)
- [Themida unpacking thread at eXeL@B forums (Russian)](https://exelab.ru/F/index.php?action=vthread&forum=13&topic=16798)